# Angular 2 Unit Testing Services with HTTP requests

Tags: testing, jasmine, angular2-services

I am new to testing services with Angular 2 and I am trying to test a service with Http basic requests (Get and GetBYId). 
- How works my service? : I have a getAllMyProducts method which consumes a REST Api exposed in a Spring boot Backend application .this web api query the products and return products for the current user.(The http request is sent with headers ).
- What I want to do? : Now I have to test this GetAll method with Jasmine and I am not sure how to do that especially regarding the current user…

1. My GetAllMethod in my Service:

```js
getAll(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.baseapiService.getAll('/product/userProducts');
    }
```

2. my baseapiService that attachs header to the request:

```js
getAll(link){
    this.header = this.createHeader();
    return this.http.get(this.apiurl+link, this.header)
      .map(this.extractData);
  }
```

Any examlpes or suggestions would be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: getAll in the service *doesn't* make Http requests, it just calls the base service method. If you're still using v2 (why?) see https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html on testing Angular generally. For the actual request part see https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/index/MockBackend-class.html.

Comment: it does call the base service which make the http request.. anyway thanks for the recommendation

Comment: Yes, but you'd test them in isolation, separately; that's the whole point of unit testing.

Comment: yes I know, the problem is that I did't figure out how to make the test